# Error static transform publisher

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ERROR: cannot launch node of type
> [tf/static_transform_publisher]: can't
> locate node
> [static_transform_publisher] in
> package [tf]

I am doing amcl laser scan on stage simulator and I've got this error when I try to roslaunch my .launch file.

Here's my launch file. ( I split it into two .launch file)

**stage_simulate.launch**

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>
  <!-- Run the map server -->
  <!-- <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" />-->
  <!--<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find my_map_package)/mymap.yaml"/>--> 
   <!--- Run AMCL -->
  <!-- <include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_omni.launch" /> -->
  <!--- stage world -->
    <node pkg="stage" type="stageros" name="stage" cwd="node" args="/home/user/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/worldmap/willow-four-erratics.world" respawn="false" output="screen">
  </node>
  <!--- dynamic_reconfigure -->
  <node pkg="dynamic_reconfigure" type="reconfigure_gui" respawn="false" name="reconfigure_gui" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

**stage_split.launch**

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>
 <!--- rviz -->
  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" respawn="false" name="rviz" args="/home/user/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/worldmap/display_config.vcg" output="screen"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="tf_broadcaster" args="1 0 0 0 0 0 base_link base_scan 100" />
</launch>
```

***Output from stage_simulate.launch***

```
... logging to /home/user/.ros/log/94773422-264c-11e3-9636-0022fb8421da/roslaunch-ubuntu-3214.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

WARNING: ignoring defunct <master /> tag
started roslaunch server htp://ubuntu:35981/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /
    reconfigure_gui (dynamic_reconfigure/reconfigure_gui)
    stage (stage/stageros)

ROS_MASTER_URI=htp://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[stage-1]: started with pid [3234]
process[reconfigure_gui-2]: started with pid [3235]
 [Loading /home/user/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/worldmap/willow-four-erratics.world][Image "willow-full.pgm"]
[ INFO] [1380159864.910827049]: found 1 position/laser pair in the file
reconfigure_gui started
```

***Output of stage_split.launch***

```
... logging to /home/user/.ros/log/94773422-264c-11e3-9636-0022fb8421da/roslaunch-ubuntu-3581.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

WARNING: ignoring defunct <master /> tag
started roslaunch server htp://ubuntu:33620/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /
    rviz (rviz/rviz)
    tf_broadcaster (tf/static_transform_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=htp://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[rviz-1]: started with pid [3607]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [tf/static_transform_publisher]: can't locate node [static_transform_publisher] in package [tf]
[ INFO] [1380159895.148350411]: rviz revision number 1.8.17
[ INFO] [1380159895.148487370]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1380159895.278180259]: Loading general config from [/home/user/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1380159896.729459922, 31.700000000]: Texture for pass 0: creating with size 1 x 1
[ INFO] [1380159896.730790120, 31.700000000]: Texture for pass 1: creating with size 1 x 1
[ WARN] [1380159897.604848196, 32.500000000]: Message from [/stage] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [base_laser_link]. Resolved locally to [/base_laser_link].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[ WARN] [1380160015.008231130, 149.900000000]: Message from [/stage] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [base_laser_link]. Resolved locally to [/base_laser_link].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[ WARN] [1380160057.864622087, 192.800000000]: Message from [/amcl] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [map]. Resolved locally to [/map].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[ INFO] [1380160065.010482674, 200.000000000]: Setting pose: 22.655 12.758 1.481 [frame=/map]
```

***Output of env|grep ROS***

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/common-lisp/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/user/fuerte_workspace:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib:/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=htp://localhost:11311
ROS_DISTRO=fuerte
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/fuerte/etc/ros
```

***env|grep PATH***

```
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/user/fuerte_workspace:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib:/opt/ros/fuerte/share
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/lib:
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
PATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
```

***Output of find /opt/ros/fuerte/ -name "static_transform_publisher" -exec ls -l {} ;***

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 298093 May  3 08:51 /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry_experimental/tf2_ros/bin/static_transform_publisher
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 383840 May  3 04:25 /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf/bin/static_transform_publisher
```

***Output of roscd tf ; ls -l bin |grep static***

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  383840 May  3 04:25 static_transform_publisher
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82876/error-static-transform-publisher/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-09-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-09-24**:
I don't see anything wrong with the syntax of your launch file.  What version of ROS are you on?  Do you have `tf` properly installed?  What happens if you execute `rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 1 0 0 0 0 0 base_link base_scan 100`?

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-09-24**:
I am using fuerte. Nothing actually happen. Another problem happened when I launch the second .launch file. [ WARN] [1380074027.654405625]: Message from [/stage] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [base_laser_link]. Resolved locally to [/base_laser_link].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.

**Comment by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) on 2013-09-24**:
Do you mean nothing happens when you try `rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 1 0 0 0 0 0 base_link base_scan 100`? No output at all? Just return to the prompt? (note: the number of parameters in that rosrun command is wrong. You need another number before base_link as a quaternion is 4 numbers).

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-09-24**:
No return to the prompt, I must Ctrl+C to stop it even though there is nothing. How is it suppose to be like? I actually refer to tf tutorial of ROS. Quaternion is something like 0 0 0 1?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-24**:
Actually 3 arguments for rotation is OK. In that case it interprets those as euler angles.

**Comment by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) on 2013-09-25**:
No output to the screen is the behaviour when it is working successfully. It shouldn't put output to the screen; instead it publishes to the /tf topic. You can see if the transform is broadcasting by typing `rosrun tf view_frames` or suchlike in another terminal. Thanks for the correction dornhege.

**Comment by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) on 2013-09-25**:
So the rosrun command seems to be working but not the roslaunch. This may help others help you: give the output of `env|grep ROS` and `env|grep PATH`. Also do give the full command you use to launch the roslaunch file and its full output. You can edit the question and add it to the bottom.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-25**:
Does the rviz node in the same launch come up?

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-09-25**:
Due to my karma I can't post link so the http has been reduced to htp. Hope understand.

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-09-25**:
@dornhege yes it does.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-25**:
This seems really odd to me. If you launch `view_frames` instead of the `static_transform_publisher` does that work?

**Comment by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) on 2013-09-26**:
Also, what is the output of the following commands: `find /opt/ros/fuerte/ -name "static_transform_publisher" -exec ls -l \{} \;` and `roscd tf ; ls -l bin |grep static` - maybe it got moved? Both commands should find the executable and get some information about it.

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-09-26**:
I have updated the output.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-26**:
What is `rospack find tf` for you?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-26**:
And just to be sure, can you do `source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash` before you start the launch file to make sure there is a clean setup.

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-09-26**:
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf

**Comment by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) on 2013-10-02**:
To be clear, we seem to have established that rospack, rosrun both find tf and static_transform_publisher is in the right place. It seems to have the right permissions. It is a bit of a mystery why it is not working in your launch file as the launch file seems right.

**Comment by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) on 2013-10-02**:
Perhaps you can for now just continue to use the rosrun command to run the static_transform_publisher and remove that part of the roslaunch file? As the `<node pkg="tf..../>` part of the launch file and the 1rosrun tf static_transform_pub...` do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might be one, suboptimal, answer for you. Check out the following question:

[roslaunch error](http://answers.ros.org/question/67488/roslaunch-error-error-cannot-launch-node-of-type/)

The user fixed it by recreating the package in question and copying appropriate files across. They never tracked down the real cause of the problem.

Actually if this answer works for you (don't forget to make the backups!) then you'd probably be doing the community a service if you explored what the problematic difference is between the failing package and the recreated one (by using a backup of the problematic package and reintroducing its differences one by one). Things to pay particular attention to are file permissions, hidden and configuration files, different file contents.

---

Originally posted by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) with karma: 399 on 2013-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) on 2013-10-02**:
If you just want to get the transform in the launch file running, then running the rosrun command like this would be enough: `rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 1 0 0 0 0 0 base_link base_scan 100`.

**Comment by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) on 2013-10-02**:
Check that this works by calling `rosrun tf view_frames` in another terminal and look at the PDF file. There should be a link between base_link and base_scan. This way you wouldn't need to fix the launch file problem (though you should probably do that too).